# How Window authentication works on SQL server?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

How Window authentication works on SQL server?

While using Windows authentication mode several questions come into mind.

- User is not member of any group in login account then how window
  authentication work means using my window credential?
- If No user not member then which account is used by sql server?
  Awaiting for your responses

Comment: Read SQL Server Books Online, topic *Database Engine->Security and Protection->Identity and Access Control*.

Comment: I agree with @KenWhite, yet Windows authentication is quite simple to understand. So, the basic is that you cannot use Windows without logging into Windows. As soon as you are logged in to your Windows, these exact credentials will be used to authenticate yourself with the server. If you don't have a login on the server then you're not accepted. If the server doesn't trust your computer then you're not getting in either (domain logins). But as I said, this is just the basic idea behind it all. Reading more about it is definitely a good idea.